# AWS extending AbstractWaiter class maximum execution time

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Im getting this error:

PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in \Aws\Common\Waiter\AbstractWaiter.php on line 135

Is there any way i could extend the maximum execution time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is error is not caused by the AWS SDK for PHP, it is caused by your PHP environment. You will need to use the [`set_time_limit()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) or the corresponding INI setting to allow your PHP scripts to run longer than 30 seconds. Without configuring that, you will probably see that error when you use any of the SDK's waiters.